# Java - Import main class in subfolder for Image

Tags: java, javafx

in my project I need to create an image for each object when is created.

```
    public abstract class Pirate extends ImageView {
    protected static int pirateSpeed, pirateScore;
    protected String word;

    public Pirate(String face, String word) {
        this.setImage(new Image(PiratesAndTreasures.class.getResource("/resources/" + face).toExternalForm()));
        this.word = word;
    }
}
```

PiratesAndTreasures is the main class and the project structure looks like this:

[image]

As far as I understood I need to access main class when I am using this:

```
new Image(TheMainClass.class.getResource("/resources/" + picture).toExternalForm()));
```

..well here is the issue: I couldn't find a way to import from an upper folder or from the "src".

Any help would be much appreciated.

UPDATE: It states "Cannot resolve symbol PiratesAndTreasures"

Comment: One reason you might have problems with this is that in the screenshot you see the source tree directory, this however is not necessary how the files are put together (relative path) on the classpath. You probably should add some details how your manifest itself and how your binary structure does look like.

Comment: One way is to provide the absolute path to your resource. Example: "C:\Project\...\java\main\src\<FileName>"

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understood; From the Pirate class I need to import PiratesAndTreasures (which is the main class) and I cannot manage to do that, either by package or whatever. I need to import that as I cannot create the image for the Pirate class.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using `ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/resources/" + picture))` That way its not dependent on wherever the main class is. This should work the same as what you have above since all these sub folders are under src.

Comment: I believe that getResource() will automatically look under the /resources directory. Is there a need to provide "/resources/" under it?

Comment: I need the Pirate class to extend ImageView.

Comment: getResource() doesn't look for a folder name resources it gets a specified data type (e.g. audio, pictures, text files etc) so you still need to tell it what folder to look in and what file to get. Hence the "/resources/"